# Get a mysqli row display under data in json

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a mysqli table that looks like this:

[image: Link to Picture of table]

out of this table I am creating a Json-File to use this later in other Files.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$categories = Category::getTopCategories();
$categories = array_values($categories);
echo json_encode($categories);

class Category
{
    /**
     * The information stored in the database for each category
     */
    public $id;
    public $parent;
    public $name;
    public $vlink;

    // The child categories
    public $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Get the child categories when we get this category
        $this->getChildCategories();
    }

    /**
     * Get the child categories
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChildCategories()
    {
        if ($this->children) {
            return $this->children;
        }
        return $this->children = self::getCategories("parent = {$this->id}");
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * The top-level categories (i.e. no parent)
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getTopCategories()
    {
        return self::getCategories('parent = 0');
    }

    /**
     * Get categories from the database.
     * @param string $where Conditions for the returned rows to meet
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getCategories($where = '')
    {
        if ($where) $where = " WHERE $where";
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','praktikum');
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"UTF8"); 

        $sql = "SELECT id,name,parent,vlink FROM mdl_praktikum$where";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $categories = array();
        while ($category = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'Category'))
            $categories[] = $category;

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return $categories;
    }
}



?>
```

and this is a snippet of my result:

```
[{
    "id": "1"
    , "parent": "0"
    , "name": "root"
    , "vlink": "0"          //this is wrong
    , "children": [{
        "id": "2"
        , "parent": "1"
        , "name": "Verschiedenes"
        , "vlink": "0"
        , "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "3"
        , "parent": "1"
        , "name": "EBSN"
        , "vlink": "0"
        , "children": [{
            "id": "6"
            , "parent": "3"
            , "name": "EBSN 1415"
            , "vlink": "0"
            , "children": [{
                "id": "23"
                , "parent": "6"
                , "name": "General Information"
                , "vlink": "0"
                , "children": [{
                    "id": "208"
                    , "parent": "23"
                    , "name": "03-05 SocialMediaMining3"
                    , "vlink": "198"
                    , "children": []
                }, {
                    "id": "209"
                    , "parent": "23"
                    , "name": "06-08 Business Model Blocks - Relationship"
                    , "vlink": "221"
                    , "children": []
                }, {........
```

Now I want to have the row "vlink" displayed as a dataobject that the json-file looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1"
    , "parent": "0"
    , "name": "root"
    , "data": {
    , "data": {"vlink": "0"}              // This should be standing here
    , "children": [{
        "id": "2"
        , "parent": "1"
        , "name": "Verschiedenes"
        , "data": { "vlink": "0"}
        , "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "3"
        , "parent": "1"
        , "name": "EBSN"
        , "data": { "vlink": "0"}
        , "children": [{
            "id": "6"
            , "parent": "3"
            , "name": "EBSN 1415"
            , "data": { "vlink": "0"}
            , "children": [{
                "id": "23"
                , "parent": "6"
                , "name": "General Information"
                , "data": { "vlink": "0"}
                , "children": [{
                    "id": "208"
                    , "parent": "23"
                    , "name": "03-05 SocialMediaMining3"
                    , "data": { "vlink": "198"}
                    , "children": []
                }, {
                    "id": "209"
                    , "parent": "23"
                    , "name": "06-08 Business Model Blocks - Relationship"
                    , "data": { "vlink": "221"}
                    , "children": []
                }, {......
```

I cant get up with the answer, what I habe to change in my code or if I have to change something in my table to get this displayed correctly....

Hope you understand what I am trying to do

Greetings Armin

Comment: There's no such thing as a "mysqli table". MySQL is the database, `mysqli` is an API for accessing it from PHP.

Comment: You really want to have `data:` and everything else nested inside another `data:` key?

Comment: I wonder if you really got the picture of the desired structure right. The indentation doesn't match the brace nesting. You have a comma at the beginning of an object: `data: {, data: { vlink: 0 }`. And you only have this doubled `data:` nesting in the first object, not the nested objects.

Comment: @aladin are you requesting that the vlink element be at the same level of hierarchy as an element called "data"?  this seems counter intuitive since children, vlink, name, and id are all one or many to the one category.  what is the goal of nesting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
    while ($category = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'Category')) {
        $vlink = array('vlink' => $category->vlink);
        unset($category->vlink);
        $category->data = $vlink;
        $categories[] = $category;
    }
```

This removes the `vlink` property from the row object, replacing it with a `data` property that contains the vlink as an object. It's actually a PHP associative array, but both associative arrays and objects turn into objects when encoded as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't call a constructor from a static function.  That only runs when an actual object instance is created.  Also, one only needs one recursive loop to pick up recursively descending children.

Edit: Ah, and to move that vlink into a data element, copy and unset it.

```
$categories = Category::getCategories();
echo '<pre>'.json_encode($categories);

class Category
{
    /**
     * The information stored in the database for each category
     */
    public $id;
    public $parent;
    public $name;
    public $vlink;

    // The child categories
    public $children;

    /**
     * Get categories from the database.
     * @param string $where Conditions for the returned rows to meet
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getCategories($parent_id='0')
    {

        $parent_id = (integer) $parent_id;
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','praktikum');
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"UTF8");

        $sql = "SELECT id, name, parent, vlink FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = $parent_id";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $categories = array();
        while ($category = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'Category')) {
            $category->children = Self::getCategories($category->id);
            $category->data = array('vlink'=>$category->vlink);
            unset($category->vlink);
            $categories[] = $category;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        return $categories;
    }
}
```